# CSS tr:hover and anchor tags

Tags: html, css

in my stylesheet, my links are styled like this:

```
a {color:#0088cc; text-decoration:none;border-bottom: 1px dotted #0088cc;}
```

and my tables are styled like this:

```
.datagridStyle { width: 100%; }
.datagridStyle th { color: #aaaaaa; padding: 8px 4px 8px 4px; background-color: #000000; background-image: url(/Content/Images/BarBGR.gif); }
    .datagridStyle th:hover { color: #eeeeee; background-color: #333333; }
.datagridStyle td { border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b6b6; padding: 6px; }
/* THIS STYLE IS THE ONE OF INTEREST */
.datagridStyle tr:hover { padding: 2px; background-color: #0083c4; color: #ffffff; cursor: pointer; }
```

problem is when I hover over a row, the row turns blue and the text turns white, but if any of the text is a link, it stays blue and hence, invisible.  How do I style the a tags inside my table to change to white too when the mouse hovers over the row and turns it blue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
.datagridStyle tr:hover a { color: #ffffff; }
```

Which will style all the links in `.datagridStyle tr:hover` to be white as well.

Comment: doh, why didn't I think of that... I love easy answers :)  thanks dken!